# Screen and Mouse Freeze - no way out - lubuntu firefox

Tags: mouse, screen, lockup

The screen and mouse freeze using Firefox - Lubuntu. I've tried every key combination I can think of and nothing works. Is there a failsafe key combination to get out of freeze?

Answer (score 0):

If the screen and mouse are the only things that have locked up, maybe you can use the keyboard to switch to a text console and then kill the offending process that is clogging up the system.

In Linux, CTRL-ALT-F1/F2/F3/etc are typically the control keys used to switch from console to console. In the old days, CTRL-ALT-F7 was typically where the graphical X11 console resided at, but now a days in Ubuntu 18.04, CTRL-ALT-F1 or sometimes CTRL-ALT-F2 is typically where I see the GUI on my machine. The other CTRL-ALT-Fx keys have text consoles.

BTW, some versions of Linux seem to only respond to the left hand CTRL-ALT buttons. I just tried my Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to let me switch consoles with either side CTRL-ALT-Fx keys. YMMV.

Once you're at a text console, login and you'll be dropped into a command line terminal. From there, you can use commands to try to find the offending process and kill it:

```
ps ax
kill -9 XXXX
```

(replace XXXX with the process ID number obtained from "ps ax")

You could also find the "top" command useful for seeing if there is a process that is stealing 100% of the CPU cycles or taking up more RAM than available.

If you know the name of the process you want to kill, you could use "ps ax | grep firefox" for example, to make it easier to find the exact process ID number than scrolling through the entire list of processes. That little vertical line character is the "pipe" character, which is typically found on your keyboard by pressing SHIFT and the "\" key.

Good luck to you!